# dojox.av.FLAudio and Adobe flash player

Tags: dojo

Our application use dojox.av.FlAudio to load and play a mp3 file. This was tested years back. Recently, when we tested this feature, it is not working in any of the browsers. Want to know if dojox.av.FlAudio requires Adobe flash player to play the mp3 file. As Adobe flash player is no longer supported by browsers, Will it be having any impact using dojox.av.FlAudio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `dojo.av.FIAudio` uses Adobe Flash (swf) to play sounds. See [documentation about htis](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/av/FLAudio.html). I'm sure you could replace it with the standard `HTMLAudioElement` element. This work acros all browsers now. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) for more information.